# How to handle a PATCH request for a nested Serializer?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to build an endpoint using Django Rest Framework for the device detail endpoint on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/controller/device/<pk>/`

Models:-

#### Device Model

```
class AbstractDevice(OrgMixin, BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    mac_address = models.CharField()
    key = KeyField()
    model = models.CharField()
    os = models.CharField()
    system = models.CharField()
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text=_('internal notes'))
    last_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    management_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    hardware_id = models.CharField()
```

#### Config Model

```
class AbstractConfig(BaseConfig):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    templates = SortedManyToManyField()
    vpn = models.ManyToManyField()
    STATUS = Choices('modified', 'applied', 'error')
    status = StatusField()
    context = JSONField()
```

For the above models, I have created serializers as:-

#### DeviceConfigSerializer

```
class DeviceConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config = serializers.JSONField()
    context = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ['backend', 'status', 'templates', 'context', 'config']
```

#### DevicedetailSerializer

```
class DeviceDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config = DeviceConfigSerializer()

    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Device
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'organization',
            'mac_address',
            'key',
            'last_ip',
            'management_ip',
            'model',
            'os',
            'system',
            'notes',
            'config',
        ]
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.name = validated_data['name']
        instance.organization = validated_data['organization']
        instance.mac_address = validated_data['mac_address']
        instance.key = validated_data['key']
        instance.last_ip = validated_data['last_ip']
        instance.management_ip = validated_data['management_ip']
        instance.model = validated_data['model']
        instance.os = validated_data['os']
        instance.system = validated_data['system']
        instance.notes = validated_data['notes']
        instance.config.backend = validated_data['config']['backend']
        instance.config.status = validated_data['config']['status']

        config_templates = validated_data['config']['templates']
        instance.config.templates.clear()
        for template in config_templates:
            instance.config.templates.add(template.pk)

        instance.config.context = json.loads(
            json.dumps(validated_data['config']['context']),
            object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict,
        )
        instance.config.config = json.loads(
            json.dumps(validated_data['config']['config']),
            object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict,
        )
        instance.save()
        instance.config.save()
        return instance
```

Since I want to incorporate a nested serializer and to make it writable so, it is required to manually add the `.update` method.

and the views:

#### Views

```
class DeviceDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeviceDetailSerializer
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
```

The above codes work fine for `PUT` request but when I try to send a patch request, it expects all the fields, i., until I feed all the fields, I am not able to send the request, but then this is not a patch request when I have to feed all the fields for changing a single field.

ps: I have abstracted the representation of the models for this questions, and tried to give an idea of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for your first doubt patch request expects all the fields:

when you are writing `instance.organization = validated_data['organization']` you are not checking if the `key` is actually present or not.
so, for that you can do it like `validated_data.get('organization')`. This represents if you have organization present in validated data then you your variable will be assigned.

you are fetching all the validated data into variables and then you are trying to update it but you can do it easily with this code.

```
instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
return instance
```

This will only update yourfields which is only present in validated_data. It will not update the other fields.

2. for the second doubt you also want to update the nested serializer fields

you can just get the data from the validated_data and update it.

In this case what you have done is correct and i think it will work perfect.

If you still face any issue, please reply me in this thread i will try to give you answer.

Comment: Hi, I followed what you said, and after this my code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/H4yM42jX

Am I doing smething wrong here.

Comment: You need not to write 
`instance.name = validated_data.get('name')
 instance.organization = validated_data.get('organization')`
after you write `instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)`
because it will automatically update the data which you have sent in patch request.
this is only for device model. for the config model fields update what you are doing is correct.

Comment: and the error is because of you are not passing the `mac_address` field in patch request and you have not mentioned `null=true` in mac_address field(Device model). so, add null=true in mac_address field and then create and run migration.

Comment: Hi, @Tarun Thanx for helping out, Could you please help me one last time, Whenever I am updating with PUT/PATCH request, the data gets updated but, I don't see the updated data in the browsable API page after it, I just have to refresh my page once more to see my updated data. heres the code : https://pastebin.com/8Ky317GA

Comment: What I expect is when my patch/put request gets completed successfully, the page should display the updated data and not the past data.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `partial=True`

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates

Comment: Have tried this way but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

`partial` will work here. So it would be like

```
s = DeviceDetailSerializer(instance, data={'name': 'Manish'}, partial=True)
s.is_valid()
s.save()
```

If you are hitting the URL with the `patch` request, it will automatically pass the `partial` argument.

The only issue I found with your code is

1. Why you are doing `self.Meta.model(**validated_data)`? because in update method `self.instance` would always be there
2. When you are doing `instance.organization = validated_data['organization']`, you are not checking whether the `key` is actually present in `validated_data` or not. So you need to check first whether the key is present or not and if the key is present only then update the data. For that, you can do `if 'organization' in validated_data` then do `instance.organization = validated_data['organization']`

Everything else looks good, If you still face any issue, please update the description with that issue for better understanding.

Comment: Okay I see! If I go according to your second point, will I not be required to check for every key if that is present in the validated_data or not. if yes then is there any other way to do it.

And in `s = ...(...., {data = {'key': 'value', }}` here if i do in this way I will have to again provide all the key,value pair again before saving. or am I understanding something wrong. It will be awesome if you can edit my codes.

Comment: @ManishShah Seems it is answered in above response. So no need to update your code. Please let me know if anything else is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can override patch method with partial=True

```
class DeviceDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeviceDetailSerializer
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True 
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

or you can try this method, for this you have to write patch manually
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates

```
# Update `comment` with partial data
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data={'content': 'foo bar'}, partial=True)
```

Comment: I tried this @Amorjot, but this doesn't resolve my problem. Still, it is prompting me to fill all the fields when I try a Patch request.